# How to save prefixSpan results into files using Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

Given results generated from prefixSpan model, How to save all results into files with sorted order by frequency? The result's data structure can't directly support saveAsTextFile function.

```
result = model.freqSequences().collect()
print result
for fs in result:
    print('{}, {}'.format(fs.sequence,fs.freq))
```

The expected results are something like:

```
[[20],[3]], 8,11.42%
[[7]], 6,8.57%
[[13]], 2,2.85%
```

Comment: you tagged this with Scala, but your code looks more like `python`..

Comment: yes, I copied python code, but preferred scala solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to save the `freqSequences`, simply don't call `collect` on that RDD and you can save it into a text file:

```
model.freqSequences().saveAsTextFile("path")
```

**However**, that might not be that useful, as it will save the result of `toString` on each of the RDD's records (of type `PrefixSpan.FreqSequence[Item]`) which might not be too easily parsed later on. So - you can format these records into Strings yourself to write them in a format you'll be able to use:

```
// Format an array using brackets, if that's how you want it; 
// You can implement whatever format you want...
def format[T](t: T): String = t match {
  case a: Array[_] => a.map(t => s"[${format(t)}]").mkString(",")
  case _ => t.toString
}

model.freqSequences()
  .map(fs => s"${format(fs.sequence)}, ${fs.freq}")
  .saveAsTextFile("path")
```

Lastly, if you're saving these results in order to apply this model using Spark later, consider using `save` directly:

```
model.save(sc, "path")
```

Which can later be loaded using:

```
PrefixSpanModel.load(sc, "path")
```

Comment: I need to save collected data for next-step processing, instead of saving the model. Once the results are collected, saveAsTextFile not work in this case.
model.freqSequences().saveAsTextFile("path") is not useful to me as I need to parse data for the following step.
Currently I simply use foreach function to save each result into files using Java.io. but I'm not sure if there is any better practice.

Comment: "`model.freqSequences().saveAsTextFile("path")` is not useful to me as I need to parse data for the following step" - can you clarify? Why is that not useful? Is it because you want to control the _format_ of the written records?

Comment: updated the answer assuming that's the issue - hope this helps

Comment: result is like this : [Ljava.lang.String;@307a2be8, 53, fs.sequence has to be parsed.